# Get the level of nodes

Tags: xslt

I want to get the level of `<li>` in  my input

input:

```
<ol start="1" style="1">
        <li>
            <p type="List Number Level 1">Text 1.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p type="List Number Level 1">Text 2</p>
            <ol start="1">
                <liFormat><iRef style="a"/>)<t/></liFormat>
                <li>
                    <p type="List Number Level 2">Text 3.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p type="List Number Level 2">Text 4.</p>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p type="List Number Level 1">Text 5.</p>
        </li>
</ol>
```

Output should be :

```
<ol start="1" style="1">
        <li>
            <p type="List_1_First">Text 1.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p type="List_1_First">Text 2</p>
            <ol start="1">
                <liFormat><liRef style="a"/>)<t/></liFormat>
                <li>
                    <p type="List_2_First">Text 3.</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p type="List_2_First">Text 4.</p>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p type="List_1_First">Text 5.</p>
        </li>
</ol>
```

Tried code :

```
<xsl:template match="ol[@start]/li[1]/p[contains(@type,'List')]" priority="30">
    <p type="List_{count(li)}_First">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Here all things have been implemented as i expected. But I have to take the level of `li`. ex : `List_{li level}_First` . Nut that par not working properly. I have mentioned my tried code. I am using xslt 2.0.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to count the ancestors here:

```
<tps:p type="List_{count(ancestor::tps:li)}_First">
```

Maybe you have other templates in your XSLT, but your current template only matches the first `li` element under the `ol`. To get your expected output, maybe you need to do this...

```
<xsl:template match="tps:ol[@start]/tps:li/tps:p[contains(@type,'List')]" priority="30">
```

See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEamKJ for an example.